# JQuery DataTables - Filtering a recordset

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've been trying to get a handle on filtering in JQuery DataTables and am having some trouble figuring it all out.

My code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        columnDefs: [{
            targets: [2, 4, 5],
            visible: false
        }, {
            targets: 1,
            width: '30%'
        }]
    });

    var filteredAge = table
        .column(3)
        .data()
        .filter(function(value, index) {
            return value > 40 ? true : false;
        });
    console.log(filteredAge);

    var filteredData = table
        .columns([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
        .data()
        .eq(3)
        .filter(function(value, index) {
            return value > 40 ? true : false;
        });
    console.log(filteredData);
});
```

As you guys will see from the following [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rmawani/e77xzvnh/4/), the first filter on a single column works fine and logs the correct values to the console, as expected. However, the second filter returns a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of null" error to the console. For the life of me, I just cannot figure out the cause.

Is my syntax wrong or did I miss something important somewhere?

Thanks in advance!

R

Comment: The cause is the `.eq(3)`. Why do you have that?

Comment: Well, the reason I have `.eq(3)` there is that, according to the [docs](https://datatables.net/reference/api/filter()), it looks to be required in order to filter data from multiple columns. I'm assuming that it is the only way for you to let the API know what column to filter based on. When I remove `.eq(3)` from the code in Fiddle, it just returns an empty recordset, which should not be the case in that example...

Comment: After doing a little more research on the issue I'm having as well as re-reading the docs for `eq()`, I believe I have found a good solution for my needs.

Please take a look at the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rmawani/e77xzvnh/) with my workaround.

If anyone sees any issues with this way of filtering the original recordset and redrawing the DataTable with the newly derived (filtered) data, please do let me know...